# WinApi and work with several domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, winapi, active-directory

I have got:

- ASP net app and application pool in the domain A
- Several domain (A, B, C)
- Users and password for connect to the domains A, B, C

What the functions of WinApi can I use, that get the members of the domain groups using  login and password for this domain?

Will whether the function "NetGroupEnum"  or "NetLocalGroupEnum" working for the domains B and C if my app working in the domain A?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about **network domains** or **app domains**?

Comment: The network domains.